# Java Instance position

Tags: java, class, instances

When making a instance of another class, i have noticed the positioning of where you create the instance can either provoke a lot of errors, or work. Let me use this example

```
public class Main() {
    Main(){

    }

    Camera camera = new Camera();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box box = new Box();
    }
}
```

What is the difference between these two different instances? I have a slight idea it has to do with static referencing but i am not sure. Also, under what conditions would you create a instance inside or outside of the static main? Thank you for your time.

Comment: You might be interested in some [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). In particular, the [Language Basics tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/index.html) should be able to help you out (look at the [Variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) section).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you have presented, `Main` is a class, with a constructor `Main()`, a field `camera` of type `Camera` (with package-local visibility), and a static method `main(String[])`. Note that the static method `main(String[])` is not the same as the class `Main` or its constructor `Main()`.

The `box` instance of type `Box` is created inside the static method `main`, and is not visible outside it, while the `camera` instance of type `Camera` is visible to every class in the same package as the current class.

Also, since `camera` is not a static field, it must be associated with an instance of type `Main`. For example, you can do this:

```
Main m = new Main();
Camera thisCamera = m.camera;
```

But not this:

```
Camera myCamera = Main.camera;
```

Comment: What makes camera a field?

Comment: A field in Java is simply a variable inside a class. As suggested by Jeffrey in the comment, the tutorials should make these concepts clear. Here's one that is a quick and easy read: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Just more elaboration of @Chthonic Project's post:

As per the example you have given it is clear that you haven't gone through the java docs

> Member variables in a class—these are called **fields**.
>
> Variables in a method or block of code—these are called **local variables**.

To elaborate this more lets take another example

```
/*Camera object is class variable*/
Camera camera = new Camera();
```

As the scope of this is at class level this becomes a class member or field.
Do not consider that only `int` or `String` can become a fields. A class object variable can also be a field or class member.

```
 /*Here the BOX object is inside a method*/
 public static void main(String[] args){
    Box box = new Box();
 }
```

A `Box box` object is declared and instantiated inside a main method. The scope of this object is **limited** to the **scope of the method**. It will be inside the curly braces of the main method only.

For e.g. suppose now modifying your exampl:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
    Box box = new Box();
    if(null != camera){
        // You can access camera inside main as it is a class member
        // the scope is a full class.
    }
 } // mian method ends.
  
 if(null == box){  // compiler will shout!!!
  // accessing box object outside main method
  // not allowed cause the box objects scope is over inside main method only.
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you do that:

```
Camera camera = new Camera();
```

You're declaring a protected attribute (field) of class Main. You're also creating an instance for this attribute.

Note that this attribute isn't static. This way, always that you create an object of class Main, a Camera will be created.

For other side, if you declare:

```
static Camera camera = new Camera();
```

Then the Java compiler will guarantee that only one instance of this attribute will exist (no matter how many objects of class Main you create).

box is a variable created inside the static void main method. This variable isn't visible (i.e. cannot be accessed) outside this method, since this variable was created inside the method (this is a standard scope rule of many languages).

Note that inside a static method is possible to reference only two kinds of variable: a local variable (as box) or a class static variable (as the example above).

Comment: I like this answer because any newbie looking at that example is going to wonder why they can't use `camera` in the `main` method.  An instance of `Main` hasn't even been created yet so there isn't a `camera` yet.

Answer (score 1):

An instance of `Main` hasn't even been created yet so there isn't a `camera` yet.  Here's how you might fix that:

```
public class Main() {
    Main(){

    }

    Camera camera = new Camera();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Box box = new Box();
        box.standOn();
        Main main = new Main(); // <- now the camera exists.
        System.out.println("Say cheese.");
        main.camera.click();
    }
}
```

By all means read the tutorials people are pointing you at.  However, the simple way to think of what's going on here is:  the static parts of an object are the parts that will work before an instance (an object) of it has been created (usually with `new`).  Sure, `static` also means every instance shares this same memory, which can be useful and cool.  But having parts of you work before you exist is pretty cool too.  After all `static void main(String[] args)` is how we get the whole show started.

By now you should have noticed how confusing it is to have `Main` the class, `main` the instance variable, and `main()` the method.  This is why we don't name our classes Main.

Comment: I understand I havnt created a instance of main i was simply asking the difference of the two instances. I didnt know if you defined a instance in a static method it also was static